# Where is Site URL setting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm setting up Facebook app following a tutorial and want to run it locally (i.e. add localhost to site url setting).

Everywhere says this should be a setting in the Facebook app but the interface has changed since every other answer.

There is "App Domains" under settings but no "Site URL". I tried adding in local URL in here but it did not allow top level domains.

I feel really dumb right now, where is this setting for site URL?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was being dumb.  I had to click "add platform" then go to website.  Time for coffee or bed!

Comment: Not so dumb. I had this issue too. Thanks for the solution.